# Error in 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a problem running this code, it always displays this error: 'ts' object must have one or more observations.

```
library('forecast')
library('tseries')
library('urca')


dataset_180days <- read.csv(file.choose())

head(dataset_180days)

# Timeseries data 
Yts_180days=ts(dataset_180days$Actual) #used to create time-series objects.

# ^--- this is where the error occurs.

# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test 
udf_test_180days <- ur.df(Yts_180days) #computes the augmented Dickey-Fuller test
summary(udf_test_180days)

# Ljung-Box Test
LB_test_180days <- Box.test(Yts_180days, type='Ljung-Box') # test statistic for examining the null hypothesis of independence in a given time series
print(LB_test_180days)

# Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) t-test

adf_test_180days <- adf.test(Yts_180days,alternative = 'stationary')
print(adf_test_180days)
```

Thank you

Attached please find the dataset.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cmwf4dema1jemw/January-2012.csv?dl=0

Comment: It is quite hard to know what is going wrong as long as we cannot see the data you are using. Can you post (a subset) of the file you are reading in? Also, it is unclear for me when the error is emitted, is it in the last print()-statement or somewhere further up?

Comment: I've edited the question and add the dataset. Otherwise, I've printed the whole code but it stuck at the 7th line: Yts_180days=ts(dataset_180days$Actual) and generate the error: 
Error in ts(dataset_180days$Actual) : 
'ts' object must have one or more observations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back here to post the solution!
Well, I had simply to change the name of the variable "Actual" on my code since I've changed the dataset ;)